# How can I make the widgets in a gtk window grow when the window resizes?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

I've tried enabling expand on the widgets in Glade but the window ends up like the pic below when I try to resize it. The widgets remain in a fixed position instead of scaling to fill the window size.

I'm new to gtk so still learning, I think this is definitely something to do with the container. I've chosen a few different containers but they all seem to have the same problem. What container should I be using for this?

[image]

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post your entire program in a code block here. It should compile cleanly and be downloadable and runnable. It should be minimal (e.g. Can you show the problem with just _one_ widget as shown in your image)? Also, in addition to the container you're currently using, do you have the code for the others you've tried?

Comment: There is no code to post, This is a glade UI project.

Comment: No code? Glade produces XML files. How about posting the XML that corresponds to the image you posted? And the XML for the other containers you've tried?

Comment: And the C code for your app that loads the XML?